# ctrl+a works when I ssh to linux machines but not on my local mac

Tags: macvim, macos

I like to use ctrl+a in vim to increase numbers. I recently upgraded my mac to Calelina, and the ctrl+a command no longer works in vim. The strange thing is, when I ssh to different linux machines, I notices ctrl+a does work in vim. How can I make ctrl+a increase numbers on my mac? Right now, when I highlight a number with the vim cursor and press ctrl+a, nothing happens.

Comment: If it works on another machine, then it's probably your local config. Does this happen when you start vim with `vim --clean`? If so, you should debug your vimrc (`:verb map <c-a>` would be a start).

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I ran `vim --clean`, but I didn't understand why until I ran `:verb map <c-a>`. It turned out I had installed a vim bundle a while ago I forgot about. After removing the bundle, ctrl+a increases numbers again. I think you should make this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a shortcut does not behave as intended, it's often due to a mapping. To check it, you can use:

```
:verb nmap <c-a>
```

- `:h :map` with zero or one argument: list mappings
- `:h :verbose`: show more info, in this case, the script, line and column where the mapping is set

If the problem is not related to a mapping, you should read [How do I debug my vimrc file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file). It mentions quite a few tips, namely `vim --clean` (one way to start vim without user configuration) is explained and debated.